# How to calculate each column and display using Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5

I'm studying about search.
I can get a only one first result.

Table name is "color" 
here is column info

```
id |  colorname 
-----------------
1      black     
2      pink
3      blue
4      pink
5      green
```

I would like to calculate each 'colorname' amount
and display list.

this is my current code

```
  public function search(Request $request)
    {

    $colors = Color::select('colorname', DB::raw('COUNT(colorname) count'))
    ->groupBy('colorname')
    ->get();

    $param = ['input' => $request->input, 'colors' =>$colors];
    return view('contacts.find', $param);
     }
```

blade file

```
    @if (isset($colors))
    <table>
    <tr>
       <td>{{$colors->getData()}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    @endif
```

MODEL

```
class Color extends Model
{

public function getData()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Comment: Hi. @Jonas Staudenmeir. I'm beginer and I've had no idea to make code so I just asked here sorry.

Comment: Do you want this result? `pink: 2 | black: 1 | blue: 1 | green: 1`

Comment: Thank you @Jonas Staudenmeir.  Yes! that is what I want result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```php
$colors = Color::select('colorname', DB::raw('COUNT(colorname) count'))
    ->groupBy('colorname')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! but I'm still having problem. I only experience useing Eloquent. I never use DB::  Do you have a way to use Eloquent?

Comment: Do you have a `Color` model?

Comment: Yes I do. I've been studing from book . it say Eloquent is good. so I only studied one haha.

Comment: Thanks! now I got this  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getData does not exist

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version?

Comment: My  version is 5.6.    I update my current code above.

Comment: Is the error coming from this line? Can you execute `dd($colors);`?

Comment: Sir There you go Collection {#188 ▼   #items: array:58

Comment: How do you use `$colors` in your controller/view?

Comment: you mean blade file? I wrote this {{$colors->getData()}}

Comment: What do you expect? Did you define `getData()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I did.  I add my model.

Comment: `$colors` is a collection, so you have to use a loop to access individual instances: `@foreach($colors as $color){{ $color->getData() }}@endforeach`

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally it worked! I rebuild my code then add your code. You are so kind. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count all the colors, and then group them by their name :

```
SELECT COUNT(colorname), colorname FROM color
GROUP BY colorname;
```

Here a SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/821d57/7/0